# Highcharts Date and Visisits array

Tags: arrays, highcharts

Have some problem with Highcharts script.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)*1000, COUNT(*) FROM visits GROUP BY DAY(time)");
DAY(date)");

$dataset[] = array();

while(list($month, $count) = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $dataset1[] = array($month, $count);
}
?>
```

result of this will be array like [time, visitors_count]. For example [1370271538, 10], [1370271233, 3]

Here is JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var graphData = <?php echo json_encode($dataset); ?>;

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Активность проекта',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Count'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ''
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Visitors',
                data: graphData !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

            }]
        });


</script>
```

How to load query result to Highcharts data correctly?

Thnx!

Comment: How your graphData looks like? COuld you paste your JSON?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in the right format, what you have will work.

Check that what you are returning is a properly formatted array of arrays, ie:

instead of:

```
 [1370271538, 10], [1370271233, 3]
```

it should be:

```
 [[1370271538000, 10], [1370271233000, 3]]
```

[[ Edited to make time stamps milliseconds ]]

Comment: Thanx! Next question:) How to put dates in X axis. Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZjSUy/12

Comment: Your timestamps need to be in milliseconds instead of seconds.  Updated answer.

Comment: I think firstly, he need to preprocess data from string format to milliseconds.

Comment: Pawel - in the fiddle I see that strings are being used.  In the example provided here, though, the data was in epoch format already.

Comment: i changed select to SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)*1000, COUNT(*) FROM visits GROUP BY DAY(time) and it wors right now:) Thanx everybody!